# Put message works in spite of catching MQException with MQ Code 2009

Tags: message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

I have a strange issue which is causing a serious double-booking problem for us.

We have an MQ.NET code written in C# running on a Windows box that has MQ Client v 7.5. The code is placing messages on the MQ queue. Once in a while the "put" operation works and the message is placed on the, but the MQException is still thrown with Error Code 2009.

In this case, the program assumes that the put operation failed and places the same message on the queue again, which is not a desirable scenario. The assumption is that if the "put" resulted in MQException the operation has failed. Any idea how to avoid this issue from happening? See the client code below.

```
queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

queueMessage = new MQMessage();
queueMessage.CharacterSet = 1208;
var utf8Enc = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInputMsg);
queueMessage.WriteBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8String).ToString());

queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

**Exception:**

```
MQ Reason code: 2009, Exception: Error in the application. 
StackTrace:    at IBM.WMQ.MQBase.throwNewMQException()
 at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Open(MQObjectDescriptor od)
 at IBM.WMQ.MQQueue..ctor(MQQueueManager qMgr, String queueName, Int32 openOptions, String queueManagerName, String dynamicQueueName, String alternateUserId)
 at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.AccessQueue(String queueName, Int32 openOptions, String queueManagerName, String dynamicQueueName, String alternateUserId)
 at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.AccessQueue(String queueName, Int32 openOptions)
```

Comment: The exception you have is from the AccessQueue rather than the Put. Could it be that the queueMessage that is resent is actually the previous one to the error i.e. you haven't reassigned queueMessage yet.

Comment: whitfiea: OK, so how do I fix that? Would re-connecting to the queue manager before the put help in fixing this issue?

Comment: It depends on if my assumption was correct. Are you reusing the queueMessage variable? Where are you catching the exception and how are you resenting the message?

Comment: queueMessage variable is created anew, as stated above. The new message thing is tracked in the database. Basically, if the MQException is caught the process exists without recognizing that the message was sent, so the process run on a scheduler re-starts 1 min later, checks the database, and seeing that the message is marked as "unsent" puts it again on the queue.

Comment: As per whitfiea's comment, the stack you show is from the open (accessqueue). You need to show your err handling code as well. If you get an exception in the accessqueue line (connection broken) then .net would drop to the next catch block. Any error handling needs to ensure that if you get an mqexception in an accessqueue that it never reaches the put anyway (good practice). Are there any calls after the put, e.g. opening a response queue, which might account for such a stack?  Check the qmgr error logs (qmgrs\XXX\errors\amqerr0?.log) as well for any messages when the 2009 occurs

Answer (score 0):

There is always an ambiguity of outcomes when using any async messaging over the network.  Consider the following steps in the API call:

1. The client sends the API call to the server.
2. The server executes the API call.
3. The result is returned to the client.

Let's say the connection is lost prior or during #1 above.  The application gets the 2009 and the message is never sent.

But what if the connection is lost after #1?  The outcome of #2 cannot possibly be returned to the calling application.  Whether the PUT succeeded or failed, it always gets back a 2009.  Maybe the message was sent and maybe it wasn't.  The application probably should take the conservative option, assume it wasn't sent, then resend it. This results in duplicate messages.

Worse is if the application is getting the message.  When the channel agent successfully gets the message and can't return it to the client then that message is irretrievably lost.  Since the application didn't specify syncpoint, it wasn't MQ that lost the message but rather the application.

This is intrinsic to all types of async messaging.  So much so that the JMS 1.1 specification specifically addresses it in *4.4.13 Duplicate Production of Messages* which states that:

> If a failure occurs between the time a client commits its work on a
>   Session and the commit method returns, the client cannot determine if
>   the transaction was committed or rolled back. The same ambiguity
>   exists when a failure occurs between the non-transactional send of a
>   PERSISTENT message and the return from the sending method.
>
> It is up to a JMS application to deal with this ambiguity. In some
>   cases, this may cause a client to produce functionally duplicate
>   messages.
>
> A message that is redelivered due to session recovery is not
>   considered a duplicate message.

This can be addressed in part by using syncpoint.  Any PUT or GET under syncpoint will be rolled back if the call fails.  The application can safely assume that it needs to PUT or GET the message again and no dupes or lost messages will result.

However, there is still the possibility that 2009 will be returned on the `COMMIT`.  At this point you do not know whether the transaction completed or not.  If it is 2-phase commit (XA) the transaction manager will reconcile the outcome correctly.  But if it is 1-Phase commit, then you are  back to not knowing whether the call succeeded or failed.

In the case that the app got a message under syncpoint, it will at least have either been processed or rolled back.  This completely eliminates the possibility of losing persistent messages due to ambiguous outcomes.  However if the app received a message and gets 2009 on the `COMMIT` then it may receive the same message again, depending on whether the connection failure occurred in #1 or #3 in the steps above.  Similarly, a 2009 when committing a `PUT` can only be dealt with by retrying the PUT.  This also potentially results in dupe messages.

So, short of using XA, any async messaging faces the possibility of duplicate messages due to connection exception and recovery.  TCP/IP has become so reliable since MQ was invented that most applications ignore this architectural constraint without detrimental effects.  Although that increased reliability in the network makes it less risky to design apps that don't gracefully handle dupes, it doesn't actually address the underlying architectural constraint.  That can only be done in code, XA being one example of that.  Many apps are written to gracefully handle dupe messages and do not need XA to address this problem.

*Note: Paul Clarke (the guy who wrote much of the MQ channel code) is quick to point out that the ambiguity exists when using bindings mode connections.  In 20 years of using WMQ I have yet to see a 2009 on a bindings mode connection but he says the shorter path to the QMgr doesn't eliminate the underlying architectural constraint any more so than does the reliable network.)*